# Blackberry Alternate Entry point - Push Global Screen Hangs

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I am working on push notifications. When i use alternate entry point for push notification, the devie's screen is hanging.But when i tried without the alternate entry point, there is no problem. How i resolve this problem ?

```
 final UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
 Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK_CANCEL, text, Dialog.OK, null, Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
 myDialog.setDialogClosedListener(new MyDialogClosedListener());
 ui.pushGlobalScreen(myDialog, 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("pus") ){
        theApp = new App();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    } else { 
        BackgroundApplication backApp=new BackgroundApplication();
        backApp.setupBackgroundApplication();
        backApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    } 
}
```

**BackgroundApplication** extends Application.

```
 try{

      final Dialog screen = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK_CANCEL, "hello",
                    Dialog.OK,
                    null,
                    Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
     final UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
     Application.getApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
     NotificationsManager.triggerImmediateEvent(0x749cb23a76c66e2dL, 0, null, null);
     ui.pushGlobalScreen(screen, 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
        }
       });
     screen.setDialogClosedListener(new MyDialogClosedListener());
       }
     catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not creating a UiApplication instance in `main` method when entering from the alternate entry point.

If it were like this, `Ui.getEngine` would return null.

EDIT
Make the bg application enter event dispatcher in main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("pus") ){
            theApp = new App();
            theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
        } else { 
            BackgroundApplication backApp=new BackgroundApplication();
            backApp.setupBackgroundApplication();
            backApp.enterEventDispatcher();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) { 
     
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("pus") ){
             theApp = new App();
             theApp.enterEventDispatcher();    
        
            } 
        else {       
        
         BackgroundApplication backApp=new BackgroundApplication();
            backApp.setupBackgroundApplication(); 
                       
       }        
    }

Comment: iam creating the app like this. now what should i do ?. iam a beginer in blackberry. so please..

Comment: Which class does `BackgroundApplication` extend from?

Comment: Downvoter: please explain. What I'm saying is quite plausible and I've run into this kind of problems in the past. I see no reason to downvote. Also you could post your own question.

Comment: @Smith -BackgroundApplication  extends from Application.

Comment: Is `BackgroundApplication` the one listening for push messages and trying to show the dialog?

Comment: yes. BackgroundApplication is listening from background. like the alternate entry point.